# Copy word textbox value to excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, textbox, transfer

I hope someone is able to help me out.  I have a word document that when you click on a command button it will launch the next for you need to fill out.  one of those forms happens to be an excel wb.  i have been able to figure out how to get the file open, but now i can't get the code i would normally use to copy/paste within excel to work.  here is where i am stuck:

```
Private Sub StudyTeam_Click()
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ThisDocument

If StudyTeam.Caption = "Completed" Then
    StudyTeam.Caption = "To Do"
    StudyTeam.BackColor = vbRed
Else
    PDate = TodaysDate.Value '//transferring textbox value to a public variables
    PTitle = Title.Text'//transferring textbox value to a public variables
    PNum = Num.Text'//transferring textbox value to a public variables
    PPI = PIName.Text'//transferring textbox value to a public variables
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Study\Study File.xlsm")
    Workbooks("Study File.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("B7").Value = PDate '//Word does not recognize this part
    '//where i think i need to start copy/paste rest of variables

    StudyTeam.Caption = "Completed"
    StudyTeam.BackColor = vbGreen
End If
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlwb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: BTW since you are using `Set xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Study\Study File.xlsm")` you can also chnage that line to something like `xlwb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B7").Value = PDate`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - your first comment is incorrect. There would be nothing wrong with the statement if it was in Excel, but in Word `Workbooks` is invalid. Your second comment isn't just a BTW as that is actually the solution.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt: Yes I missed that `xlApp.Workbooks("Study File.xlsm").Sheets(1).Range("B7").Value` Would have sorted it. But then 2nd comment is better. Deleting the first comment

Comment: Thank you everyone, i think i was staring at it for to long and it was late.  but it works perfectly now. Thanks again